# Wordpress openbase_dir issue Windows Server 2008 R2 and Plesk 11.0.9

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, plesk

Wordpress openbase_dir problem on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Plesk 11.0.9

I have just moved a website and it's wordpress database from an old windows server to a new one running Plesk and IIS7.

I have PHP enabled and the openbase dir is set to the web root and c:\Windows\Temp however I get the following error (see below). Wordpress is installed within the info folder from the root.

If anyone knows anything about the wordpress php file l10n.php that would be most helpful, it looks like I have a double path because the string it is trying to read is equal to this:

> C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/wp-content/plugins/platinum-seo-pack/platinum_seo_pack-en_US.mo

```
Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect.     File(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-    steps.com\httpdocs\info/wp-content/plugins/platinum-seo-pack/platinum_seo_pack-en_US.mo) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/creative-steps.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 322

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-includes\l10n.php:322) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-login.php on line 290

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-includes\l10n.php:322) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-login.php on line 302

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-includes\l10n.php:322) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info\wp-login.php on line 304
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about Platinum Seo Pack's plugin configuration. As you can see, this file name is incorrect.

C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/**C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/wp-content/plugins/platinum-seo-pack/platinum_seo_pack-en_US.mo**

should be

C:\Inetpub\vhosts\creative-steps.com\httpdocs\info/**wp-content/plugins/platinum-seo-pack/platinum_seo_pack-en_US.mo**

To resolve this problem, go to platinum_seo_pack.php file in wp-content\plugins\platinum-seo-pack folder. Search for load_plugin_textdomain or go to line 181 in it. Change `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` with `basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) )` in that line.

Comment: Hi Gökhan Çoban, I have commented out that line and copied it and change to the following (which doesn't work still):   load_plugin_textdomain( dirname( __FILE__ ) );